# Oscilloscope bizarrely results in clipping at some voltage resolution settings

Tags: oscilloscope, voltage-clipping

I have a Keysight InfiniiVision DSOX3024T. There is a complicated signal fed to it coming from an AriCorp TDC-30 transimpedance amplifier, with typical signal in the hundreds of mV. The signal is an average of thousands, and the nature of the signal is that its amplitude jumps around, but the shape/structure of it stays largely the same.

At some voltage resolution settings, clipping is induced, with the signal being lopped off at ~157 mV (at least for this run/resolution— I will try to see if that's a constant across multiple settings and experiments). The shape of the signal is noticeably changed, as illustrated by the two attached plots. The only thing that changed between these datasets are that I changed the vertical resolution. Again, the signal amplitude itself bounces around, but the shape is constant. As you adjust the resolution, you can watch the signal get clipped (and just for clarification, the signal is nowhere near the top of the scope screen).

I have verified this behavior with multiple channels of the scope and across both 50 and 1 MOhm terminations. I don't have any other scopes that can be used to sanity check this.

I have been very unhappy with this scope for other reasons [*], and so I naturally suspect it to be the cause. I also cannot fathom how changing any setting on the scope, and most especially a voltage resolution, could possibly alter the nature of the incoming signal.

Tomorrow I will try to get a function generator to replicate this behavior.

What else should I attempt to figure this out? Has anyone seen this before?

[image: Signal showing overall correct shape.]

[image]

[*] The scope quite astonishingly refuses to save time information to csv in full resolution. It rounds it to like 4 decimal places and then just calls it a day. I have scoured the heavens trying to figure out how to change this behavior and give me the actual un-rounded timestamps to no avail. It fortunately does not do this with the signal data, as this would render the device worthless to me. Nonetheless, I have had to write code that gets around this inexplicable 'feature' of the scope to, ya know, not plot dozens or hundreds of data points on top of one another because the timestamps all round together.

Comment: This seems likely to be an issue with the scope. And, are you sure the scope only saves four decimal places for the time, and it's not just that your csv viewer/parser rounds? I know Excel and Libreoffice Calc both do unless you make the cells wider.

Comment: W.r.t. the export issue using CSV, do you also have MATLAB available? MATLAB is listed as one of the other export options. I haven't used one of these scopes so not sure if the MATLAB export will suffer the same issue or hot.

Comment: As pointed out by @ChesterGillon, this 'scope can extend its 8-bit resolution to 12-bits by *averaging*. This will necessarily involve the 'scope's triggering subsystem. When averaging, triggering must be rock-solid, including no mis-triggered sweeps, and is especially difficult when your waveform jumps around. I'd suggest turning off averaging, and see if captured data settles down to something more sane.

Answer (score 0):

From the [datasheet](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/assets/7018-04570/data-sheets/5992-0140.pdf) linked from the [DSOX3024T Oscilloscope: 200 MHz, 4 Analog Channels](https://www.keysight.com/us/en/support/DSOX3024T/oscilloscope-200-mhz-4-analog-channels.html) page:

1. The *Vertical system analog channels* section has:

   > Vertical resolution : **8 bits** (measurement resolution is 12 bits with averaging)
   >
   > Offset range : ± 2 V (1 mV/div to 200 mV/div)
2. The *Search, navigate, and lister* section has:

   > Graticules : **8 vertical divisions** by 10 horizontal divisions with intensity controls
3. The *Acquisition mode* in the *Acquisition system* section has:

   > Averaging : Selectable from 2, 4, 8, 16, 64, ... to 65,536
   >
   > **High resolution** : Real time boxcar averaging reduces random noise and effectively increases vertical resolution **12 bits** of resolution when ≥ 10 μs/div at 5 GSa/s or ≥ 20-μs/div at 2.5 GSa/s

So, I think the DSOX3024T has an 8-bit ADC, with a *High Resolution* mode which uses averaging to increase the effective number of bits to 12.

When the *Input sensitivity range* (volts-per-division) is adjusted, presumably the anlog input section of the oscilloscope has to scale and offset the input into the range of the ADC.

From the question:

1. At 200 mV/Div the unclipped signal is shown at up to 580 mV. With 8 vertical divisions the full-scale input range will be 8 x 200 mV or 1.6 V.
2. At 50 mV/Div the clipped signal gets up to to a max of ~160 mV. With 8 vertical divisions the full-scale input range will be 8 X 50 mV or 400 mV. Where this full scale range is less than the maximum voltage shown for the unclipped signal. I'm not sure what the vertical *offset* was set to during these measurements, which could explain why the signal appeared to clip at +160 mV.

Is the issue that at a vertical resolution of 50 mV/Div, the dynamic range of the input signal exceeds that of the oscilloscope?

If the input signal doesn't go negative, perhaps adjusting the vertical offset will limit the amount of clipping.